# Make textbox bigger when more is typed (Facebook style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to mimic Facebook's exact comment feature. For example, when I type a sentence that exceeds the amount of width-space in the textbox (or a newline character is entered) the textbox should lower by one line to accomodate the new line.

*In Pictures:*

**Case 1**

[image: Case 1 Image]

I type one sentence into the textbox, does not exceed width available, so textbox does not create a new line below.

**Case 2**

[image: Case 2 Image]

I typed 4 sentences, each with new line characters associated with them. The textbox lowers by 1 line to accomodate for the last sentence, "For Example".

**Case 3**

[image: Case 3 Image]

When I add more lines the textbox should expand with more room to accomodate the new sentences.

**Case 4**

[image: Case 4 Image]

When I delete the lines the textbox size should become smaller to accomodate for the decrease of text. *Case 4's picture may look a little deceptive, but the last blank line is there because my text cursor is there.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of jQuery plugins to achive this:

> - http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize
> - http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/
> - http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea